# Check completion for multiple background jobs to show status individually

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need help with a loop to verify if background jobs have been finished in a script:

I have 2 arrays (dbs and paths) where I save the dynamic variables and I use them to execute something with those, this is working pefectly fine:

```
# This is the main definition for DBs and backup paths:
DB_AND_BKP_PATH='DB1:/backups/db1/dump1,/backups/db1/dump2,/backups/db1/dump3,/backups/db1/dump4
                 DB2:/backups/db2/dump1,/backups/db2/dump2,/backups/db2/dump3,/backups/db2/dump4
                 DB3:/backups/db3/dump1,/backups/db3/dump2,/backups/db3/dump3,/backups/db3/dump4'

# And then a function to fill the arrays dbs[] and paths[] to split each:

function get_db_and_path(){
  for line in ${DB_AND_BKP_PATH}
  do
    IFS=':'
    dbs[$i]=$(echo ${line} | awk '{print $1}')
    paths[$i]=$(echo ${line} | awk '{print $2}')
    (( i++ ))
  done
}

# Call previous function
get_db_and_path

for (( arra=1; arra<=${#dbs[@]}; arra++ ))
do
  db=${dbs[$arra]}
  paths=${paths[$arra]}
  # Function to backup:
  backup ${db} into ${paths} &
  pids[$arra]=$!:${db}
done
```

And I save the pid and db for each process in another array called pids.

Now I would like to monitor each backgroub job individually and show when they finishes, something like

```
echo "Process ${dbs[$arra]} is complete!"
echo "Wait for process: " # put here the process stills running
```

And so on for all the process launched in the "for " loop, it could be 1, 2, 3, N.

I have been looking for any solution without any success, looking for help please!

Comment: please update the question with a sample set of `dbs[]` and `paths[]` data (2-3 items should suffice), and the expected output

Comment: See [ProcessManagement - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement).

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: Bash arrays are indexed from zero so `for (( arra=1; arra<=${#dbs[@]}; arra++ ))` will miss the first element in the `dbs` array and try to access an element beyond the end of it.  You probably want `for ((arra=0; arra<${#dbs[@]}; arra++))`.

Comment: `pids[$arra]=$(echo $!:${db})` contains a useless (and potentially broken) use of command substitution (`$(...)`) and `echo`.  It can be safely replaced with `pids[$arra]=$!:${db}` or `pids[arra]=$!:$db` (removing all redundant punctuation).

Comment: I have expanded details, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Many possible solutions exist, will try to list few of them with examples

### Solution 1

Wrap `backup` in a bash function where it logs a finished backup instance.

Pros:

- Easy to implement

Cons:

- No actual progress is reported, instead you only know when a job finish

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function report_backup(){
  echo calling backup $1 $2
  sleep 1s
  echo "Done: $1 $2"
}

# simulate a for loop
report_backup db1 /path/to/db1 &
report_backup db2 /path/to/db2 &
wait
echo "All done"
```

Output would look like:

```
calling backup db1 /path/to/db1
calling backup db2 /path/to/db2
Done: db1 /path/to/db1
Done: db2 /path/to/db2
All done
```

Maybe more progress reporting can be done by say managing the progress state in some temp file where each job access it with `flock`

### Solution 2

If progress reporting is needed, you can use [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)

Pros:

- You have full control about how many parallel background jobs to invoke + rich parallel options

Cons:

- You need GNU parallel to be installed

An example

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# simulates your db to path mapping
function get_db_and_path(){
        echo "db1 path1"
        echo "db2 path2"
        echo "db3 path3"
}

function backup(){
        echo "Doing backup for $1 $2"
        sleep 1
}

export -f backup # not needed if backup is not a bash function

get_db_and_path | parallel --progress backup  # maybe add -j if needed
```

You would be seeing raw parallel progress output like

```bash
Computers / CPU cores / Max jobs to run
1:local / 2 / 2

Computer:jobs running/jobs completed/%of started jobs/Average seconds to complete
local:2/0/100%/0.0s Doing backup for db1 path1
local:2/1/100%/1.0s Doing backup for db2 path2
local:1/2/100%/1.0s Doing backup for db3 path3
local:0/3/100%/0.7s
```

Again these are not the only solutions; for me I would prefer utilizing python 3rd party libs like `tqdm` or `rich` around a pool of subprocess workers or something

Comment: Great solutions, thank you! I will absolutely try the second one.